# FormGroup with warning in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to validate my form with warning.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308209/angular-2-form-validation-for-warnings-hints). This works for `FormControl`. But I also need `FormGroup` and `FormArray` that can check if sub control has warning.

```
export class FormControlWarn extends FormControl {
  warnings: any;

  get warn(): boolean {
    return this.warnings != null;
  }
}

export class FormArrayWarn extends FormArray {
  get warn(): boolean {
    // return true if any controls under this FormArray have warning.
  }
}

export class FormGroupWarn extends FormGroup {
  get warn(): boolean {
    // return true if any controls under this FormGroup have warning.
  }
}
```

I want to create my `FormGroup` with the benefit of `FormBuilder`.
But `formBuilder.group()` returns bare `FormGroup`, looks can not return customized class.

Can I create customized `FormGroup` class with `FormBuilder`?

Comment: A FormGroup, FromArray or FormControl can be invalid and you can submit the form. Why not? Really I don't know what is the sense of create a "warning". If you want, override the ng-invalid class

Comment: 'warning' should display a message on validation like `<div *ngIf="control.warnings?.required">warning message</div>`. But the form is not invalid and the operator can submit the form.

Comment: I want to say that if you use "normal" control of errors, you write `<div *ngIf="control.errors?.required">`, why re-invent the wheel? **nobody** force you to don't send an invalid form or to disable a button if is invalid

Comment: It seems like a bad user experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormBuilder` is a utility class that just wraps constructors for `FormControl`, `FormGroup` and `FormArray`, allowing you define your form with less repetitions of endless `new FormControl()` constructor calls.

If you're adding your own form controls by extending existing ones, you should also create your own `MyFormBuilder` and then add the methods that fit with *your* use-case. There's nothing Angular car (or should) do about random classes you've extended from the existing ones.